# Efficient parameter passing in method in java

Tags: java

I have a method signature like this.

```
public void calculateFinalInvoice(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h, int i, InvoiceDO invoiceDO ) {
     // TO DO

}
```

I am passing somany parameters. So is it better to pass all these parameters performance wise. 
Or 
1) maintain a class for all this parameters
2) maintain HashMap for all these parameters
3) maintain an ArrayList for this.

Can you please suggest which one is better to achieve performance.

Comment: Is it always `a to i` number of parameters?

Comment: how often is this being called?

Comment: Use a class for code maintenance. Don't worry about performance unless you NEED to.

Comment: I'd do `calculateFinalInvoice(InvoiceDO invoiceDO, int... args)` or `calculateFinalInvoice(InvoiceDO invoiceDO, ClassOfValues values)`

Comment: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth

Answer (score 2):

What version of Java are you using?  What are you doing with those parameters.  You might be better off moving the DAO to the front of the argument list and then using `varargs` to pass however many `int`s you want:

```
calculateFinalInvoice(InvoiceDO invoiceDO, int args...) {
}
```

Comment: There is a typo in the code. It should be calculateFinalInvoice(InvoiceDO invoiceDO, int... args){}

Answer (score 1):

Do not worry about micro managing efficiency on things like this. Code for clarity and after done coding, worry about efficiency if needed. In this case, you might want to rethink your design and create some more structure to your code. For example, you might want to use arrays :

```
public void calcualteFinalInvoices(int [] invoices, InvoiceDO action){
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would dare give you a more OOP, more readable approach.

Your code sample is akin to calling `trim("my string")` instead of `"my string".trim()`. This is procedural programming, in which code works on passive data (`trim` working on `"my string"`). In OOP, we instead send messages to objects to fulfill requests, like in `"my string".trim()"`.

So the alternative identifies `Invoice` as a concept that can be asked for its value or contents. We then use [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) and [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) to get you the most readable, most maintainable program. If the different variables have special meanings, you can decorate the `Invoice` class with specific versions of `add`, like `addBalance` and so forth.

```
class Invoice {
    private final List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Invoice add(int value) {
        values.add(value);
        return this;
    }

    public double value() {
        // Use the values to compute the final invoice.
        return computedFinalInvoice;
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
double finalInvoiceValue = new Invoice()
    .add(1)
    .add(2)
    .add(100)
    .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply pass array of int

```
calculateFinalInvoice(int[] values, InvoiceDO invoiceDO) { }
```

Comment: Any how i want thiese in my service layer

Comment: @sorry didn't get you .. is there any problem passing int array?

Comment: yes  its also feasible. can it be performance wise efficient ?

Comment: if i am taking an array i have to always keep in mind in which index, which value is stored. is it better to take a Map

Comment: in the method you can assign the values to local variables if you need to use it further use  where there is a chance of ambiguity.. althourh I myself prefer passing object, but i posted this as that answer was already posted :)

Answer (score 0):

Forget about performance. This is not an issue. The issue is that exactly as formula for engineer must not exceed 1 inch the method should not get more than 3 arguments. If you need more, change your design.

You probably should create special parameter class and pass its instance to the method. Or put method to different class that stores some data as instance fields...

If you want advise concerning fixing your design ask other question where explain what are you trying to do. I believe community can help you to improve your design.

Comment: Silly rules are silly. It may be possible to find clusters of related parameters and pass them in as objects. However, any such object creation will necessarily be slower than just passing the parameters in.

Comment: Dear @Bob Dalgleish, silly rules help. Do you like method that accepts 10 arguments? Are they convenient? Are they easy to use? Think about this.

Comment: @AlexR so instead of 10 parameters to a method you have 10 parameters to a constructor, or 10 setter method calls to some new class. I agree, silly rules are silly.....